# mySQL to PostgreSQL concat first name and last name for name search (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Hey I'm trying to figure out how to convert a statement that works in mySQL into PostgreSQL and curious if anybody knows the solution.

Here is the statement that works in mySQL:

```
def self.by_name(keywords)
    if keywords
        find(:all, :conditions => ["concat(first_name," ",last_name) like?", "%#{keywords}%"])

    end
  end
```

Here is the statement that I found on [this site](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2000-07/msg00294.php) that basically had a similar problem, but it doesn't work for me, as in, if I do a search like Contact.by_name("Bobby"), there are no results.

```
def self.by_name(keywords)
    if keywords
        find(:all, :conditions => ["textcat(textcat(first_name,text ' '),last_name) like?", "%#{keywords}%"])
    end
  end
```

The idea is that I could search for "Bobby", "Fishcer", or "Bobby Fischer" and it would match anybody with either that first name, last name, or both first and last name. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [concatenation operator (`||`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) to paste everything together:

```
:conditions => [
  "coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '') ilike '%' || ? || '%'",
  keywords
]
```

You'll also notice that I switched from string interpolation, `"%#{keywords}%"`, to string concatenation in the SQL, `'%' || ? || '%'`, to build the search pattern; doing this avoids injection and quoting problems. I've also switched to [`ilike`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) since you probably want a case insensitive search.

Comment: thanks @mu is too short (damn you're quick) :) i'll try that now

Comment: i am noticing one problem with this query, is that if the last_name field for a record is nil, it will not return the result. this is a pretty unlikely case, since users would be expected to have both first and last names. i think that's why the other query i posted wasn't working, because i was adding fake records that only contained first names and figured it wouldn't matter if the last name was nil.

Comment: @masterkrang: If you have to deal with NULLs then you can use [`coalesce`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to convert them to empty strings as in my updated answer.